# After clicking buy now, cart counter does not update when user redirects back to homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used Goya theme and as per their documentation, it is working fine until the user goes back from the checkout page to the homepage. On the rest pages, the cart counter remains updated except only on the homepage. Please help.

Here is the link to complete the code,
https://goya.everthemes.com/help-center/add-a-buy-now-button/

Comment: Just ask in [Goya theme support](https://support.everthemes.com/) as it's a commercial theme.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have already done.